# Yield to a IList return type

Tags: c#, ienumerable, yield, ilist

I have to realize a serializazion/deserialization class and i'm using `System.Xml.Serialization`. I have some `IList<Decimal>` type properties and wanted to serialize in `IList<string>` decoding all decimal value belonging to the list with a specific culture info. For example `10` is `10,00` with Italian culture info but `10.00` with English culture info. 
I tried to do it using this:

```
public IList<string> method()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            yield return i.ToString();
        }
    }
```

But i get at compile time Error 33

```
The body of 'Class1.method()' cannot be an iterator block because 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<string>' is not an iterator interface type
```

If i use as property type `IEnumerable<string>` it works succesfully but obviusly i can't change the type of data i want to serialize .

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Change to `IList<string>` to `IEnumerable<string>`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`yield` only works with `IEnumerable<T>`, `IEnumerable`, `IEnumerator<T>` and `IEnumerator` as return type.
In your case, you need to use a normal method instead:

```
public IList<string> method()
{
    var result = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        result.Add(i.ToString());
    }
    return result;
}
```

Think about it. Your code would allow you to write the following code:

```
method().Add("foo");
```

That doesn't make too much sense, does it?

Comment: @Riccardo: Because that's how it is implemented: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can also move the iterator block to a private method or getter, like this:

```
public IList<string> method()
{
  return seq.ToList();
}

IEnumerable<string> seq
{
  get
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
      yield return i.ToString();
    }
  }
}
```

But also note that for the particular case of a range `x : x+1 : x+2 : ... : x+(n-1)` there's already in .NET the method [`Enumerable.Range`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range.aspx) which you could use like this:

```
public IList<string> method()
{
  return Enumerable.Range(0, 1000).Select(i => i.ToString()).ToList();
}
```